# why mesh get disturb after applying boolean

Tags: modifiers

why mesh get disturb after applying boolean. I have subsurf, boolean, edge and solidify modifier. After applying the boolean mesh get disturb. I do not want to apply subsurf modifier. How to solve it and get a clean mesh. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Why is the subsurf before the Boolean ? If you are trying to apply the Boolean, then it should have been at the top of the stack, otherwise problems always show up, the Boolean preview is based on the mesh generated by the subsurf, therefore if you apply the Boolean and still keep the subsurf, errors will show up. Also I see a solidify and an edge split after the boolean. No wonder. Very messy modelling.

Comment: Still using Booleans? Aren't [all your previous boolean-related questions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A30601+boolean) enough?

Comment: Why do you need to apply the modifier?